# calculating mean with a condition on python pandas Group by on two columns. And print only the mean for each category?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Input

```
Fruit Count Price tag
Apple  55    35   red
Orange 60    40   orange
Apple  60    36   red
Apple  70    41   red
```

Output 1

```
Fruit Mean  tag
Apple 35.5  red
Orange 40   orange
```

I need **mean** on condition price between 31 and 40

Output 2

```
    Fruit   Count  tag
    Apple   2   red
    Orange  1   orange
```

I need **count** on condition price between 31 and 40

pls help

Comment: Do you need 2 outputs? Or is possible only one with counts and mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering:

```
df1 = df[df['Price'].between(31, 40)]
print (df1)
    Fruit  Count  Price     tag
0   Apple     55     35     red
1  Orange     60     40  orange
2   Apple     60     36     red
```

If possible multiple columns by aggregated functions:

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['Fruit', 'tag'])['Price'].agg(['mean','size']).reset_index()
print (df2)
    Fruit     tag  mean  size
0   Apple     red  35.5     2
1  Orange  orange  40.0     1
```

Or 2 separately DataFrames:

```
df3 = df1.groupby(['Fruit', 'tag'], as_index=False)['Price'].mean()
print (df3)
    Fruit     tag  Price
0   Apple     red   35.5
1  Orange  orange   40.0

df4 = df1.groupby(['Fruit', 'tag'])['Price'].size().reset_index()
print (df4)
    Fruit     tag  Price
0   Apple     red      2
1  Orange  orange      1
```